# How to create New user using Asp.net mvc identity out side from Accountcontroller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, createuser

I am trying in my applicaton to add user outside from Registriation so outside Accountcontrol and i tried to add manually to database but it does not work also i need to take the hashpassword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the answer of my question:
just create a new applicationdfcontext :)

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    ApplicationUserManager _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
    var manger = _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = aspNetUsers.Email, UserName = aspNetUsers.UserName };
    var usmanger= manger.Create(user, aspNetUsers.PasswordHash);
```